# Can't make work GLKView with Swift

Tags: ios, opengl-es, swift

i'm trying to use OGLES in my Swift project.
I added customized GLKView by GLEditorView on storyboard.

Code of this class:

```
import UIKit
import GLKit
import OpenGLES

class GLEditorView: GLKView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        glClearColor(0.1, 0.3, 0.9, 1.0)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
    }
}
```

Place, where must be a GLKView is white. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems **GLKView** do not initialize his context itself.

```
class EditAreaViewController: GLKViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    (self.view as GLEditorView).context = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand; is      (self.view as GLEditorView).context = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2) equivalent to         glClearColor(0.1, 0.3, 0.9, 1.0)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
?

Comment: No. But openGL do not know which context to use for glClearColor, glClear, until you create context for GLKView yourself.